# Como consultar informacion de distintos nodos

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Estoy haciendo una pagina para que locales puedan ofrecer servicio, lo que hago es cuando registro se guardan dentro del id del usuario logueado, pero necesito consultar todos los empleados sin importar en que id se encuentren registrados

Agradecería su ayuda, para poder resolver este problema con el que llevo varios dias 
[image: La base]

Comment: Hola. Intenta construir una función de búsqueda recursiva en arrays, que te recoja todos los valores situados bajo la clave xxxx con el formato [semipath/xxxx => valor, etc.] de esa manera tienes todos los datos en valor y la clave de registro en semipath inmediatamente antes de /xxxx . No te puedo ofrecer otra sugerencia porque no uso angujarjs

Comment: Ya lo pude hacer de otra forma, mas tarde lo subiré en caso de que alguien mas tenga ese problema